# Yii model validation works, form is still posted without error

Tags: php, validation, yii

After unsuccesfully scouring Google and SO for a sollution regarding a problem with a model validation, I've decided to post my own question. Something tells me that the problem is something very small, so excuse my blindness before hand.

Problem:
I have a registration form which includes the fields `day` `month` and `year` which together need to be validated for a minimum age of 18 years.

The problem is, the method `checkAge()` seems to be firing and giving a response (I checked this using the Net reponse in Firebug Webdev Tools), except that response is not being displayed in the `<?php echo $form->error($model,'day'); ?>` placeholder, nor does the validation error prevent the form from being posted.

My other custom validation method `checkEmail()` works perfectly, the error is displayed as expected (and obviously prevents the form from being posted in case of an error).

Model:

```
class SignUpForm extends CFormModel
{
...
public $email;
public $day;
public $month;
public $year;
...

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('..., email, day, month, year, ...', 'required'),
        ....
        array('email', 'checkEmail'),
        array('day', 'checkAge'),
    );
}

public function checkEmail()
{
    $check = file_get_contents('...'); // api checks if email is in use - WORKS (!)
    if ($check == 0)
        $this->addError('email','Email is in use.');
}


public function checkAge()
{
    $this->addError('day','Age must be atleast 18 years old.');
}

    ...
```

View:

```
<div class="form signupform" id="signupform">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'signup-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),
    'action' => array('site/signup')
)); ?>

...

<div class="row select">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'day', array('class'=>'geb')); ?>
<select name="SignUpForm[day]" class="day">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option> 
    ... 
</select>
<select name="SignUpForm[month]" class="month">
    <option value="1">jan</option>
    <option value="2">feb</option>
    ... 
</select>
<select name="SignUpForm[year]" class="year">
    <option value="1996">1996</option> 
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    ...
</select>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'day'); ?>
</div>
...
```

Controller:

```
public function actionSignUp()
{
    $model=new SignUpForm;

    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='signup-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();  
    }

    if (isset($_POST['SignUpForm'])) 
    {
        $postFields = $_POST['SignUpForm'];
        // posts to api via curl
        $response= Yii::app()->curl->post('http://www.api.com/myapi.php', array(
                        ...
            'email' => $postFields['email'],
            'day' => $postFields['day'],
            'month' => $postFields['month'],
            'year' => $postFields['year'],
                        ...
        )); 
        // proces response
    }
    else
        $this->render('register', array('model'=>$model));
}
```

The response from AJAX (as seen in firebug):

```
{"SignUpForm_email":["E-mail is required.","Email is in use."],"SignUpForm_day":["Age must be atleast 18 years old."]}
```

Which means the validation is being fired, the user however does not receive any error, nor does it stop the form from being posted.

I'm lost here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is your controller code?

Comment: updated the original question.

Comment: returning true or false doesn't make a difference, see the answer from Pitchinnate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right don't need the true or false anymore on return. But I think the issue may be with your select boxes in your html. I believe you need to have the ID's setup correctly:

```
<select name="SignUpForm[day]" id="SignUpForm_day" class="day">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

It is normally better to use the built in form generators from CHTML so you don't run into issues like this. Example:

```
$options = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'day',$options);

$options = array(1=>'jan',2=>'feb',3='mar');
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'month',$options);
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem (I don't think you need to return true or false). Also the validation method `checkEmail()` doesn't return true or false, and that method works like it's supposed to.

Comment: You are correct it seems as that is no longer required see my updated answer I believe the issue is with your html ids.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that time, I added `id="SignUpForm_day"` to my HTML select element, and the problem is solved - my error gets displayed like it's supposed to. Thanks a million, and thanks for the tip for generating the dropDownList using CHtml, will definitely do that in the future.